# Getting 503 error while uploading image to cloud bucket through node js server on app engine

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, sharp

I am trying to upload images to gcp bucket and everything working fine on local & server till i m not using sharp module to compress the image but when i use sharp then it is working fine on local but it is not working on app engine and getting 503 error
"upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination"

I am trying to upload & compress image to cloud bucket through nodejs and google app engine

`

```
const uploadToGCS = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (!req.files) {
            return next();
        }
        let promises = []
        for (let i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
            const fileObj = req.files[i];
            let sharp_buffer = await sharp(fileObj.buffer).jpeg().toBuffer()
            fileObj['buffer'] = sharp_buffer
            const bucket = storage.bucket(DEFAULT_BUCKET_NAME);
            console.log("date.now",todayDatetime())
            console.log("fileObj.originalname",fileObj.originalname)
            const gcsFileName = `${Date.now()}-${fileObj.originalname}`;
            const file = bucket.file(gcsFileName);
            const stream =  file.createWriteStream({
                metadata: {
                    contentType: fileObj.mimetype,
                },
                highWaterMark: 1024 * 1024
            });
    
            stream.on('error', (err) => {
                fileObj.cloudStorageError = err;
                next(err);
            });
            promises.push(
                new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
                    stream.on('finish', async () => {
                        fileObj.cloudStorageObject = gcsFileName;
                        file.makePublic().then(() => {
                        fileObj['url'] = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${DEFAULT_BUCKET_NAME}/${gcsFileName}`
                        console.log("fileObj['url']",fileObj['url'])
                        resolve()
                        });
                    })
                })
              )
            stream.end(fileObj.buffer);
        }
        await Promise.all(promises)    
        let urlArr = []
        console.log("urlArr=>",urlArr)
        req.files.map((file) => {
            urlArr.push(file['url'])
        })
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "file uploaded", url: urlArr });

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Errror in uploadToGCS",e)
        return res.status(500).send({success:false,message:"internal server error"});
    }
    
}
```

`